# How to calculate distance between more than two points with google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Calculating distance between two point with google maps is easy and I did. But how to calculate distance between more then two marks in google map with the help of google maps api?

Comment: Do you mean pairwise, or as a path?

Comment: for example.. distance between three cities

Comment: That's unclear. Distance between each of the 3 cities? Meaning from A to B, B to C and A to C? Basically you need the coordinates of all *cities* then run a loop until you have calculated all the distances. To calculate distances, see the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), there is a `computeDistanceBetween()` method.

Comment: "is easy and I did" - how?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad use-case, But for a simple solution of your question I would recommend you using a [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). This would help you to find distances in between two or even more cities. The API request to find the distance in between 4 cities would be like this.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=API_KEY
```

This request will return four elements - two origins times two destinations:

Vancouver to San Francisco, Vancouver to Victoria,
Seattle to San Francisco &  Seattle to Victoria

Please take a look at the official Google Documentation of [Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) API to know more about the API requests for more origins and destination.

One more option for you is to use a [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), but that would cover points in a path and there respective distance.

Hope that Helps!!

Comment: bit closer to my question but still there is problem.
means getting distance from vancouver to san francisco, seattle, victoria. and then I will do total.